# Create new column that equals one of many existing columns when condition is met

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, lapply, purrr

I have a wide dataframe with election results. I need to make a new column saying how many votes a specific party received. The way the votes are recorded means that I need to loop over a large number of columns to do this. I can see how to do it with a for loop but I'd like to get it to work using `purrr`.

Here's an example of what the data looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(district = c("A", "B"),
                 party1 = c("Lab", "Con"), 
                 votes1 = c(188, 200),
                 party2 = c("LD", "Lab"),
                 votes2 = c(140, 164),
                 party3 = c("Con", "LD"),
                 votes3 = c(23, 99))
```

I want to create a new column recording how many votes the "LD" party received. So this would be, in this example:

```
df$LD_votes <- c(140,99)
```

I tied this, but without success:

```
df <- df %>% map(1:34, function(x) mutate(LD_votes = ifelse(paste0(party, x)=="LD", paste0(votes, x), NA)))
```

How can I make code along these lines work?

Answer (score 1):

Here I have a `data.table` solution. First we convert `df` to a data.table:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(district = c("A", "B"),
                 party1 = c("Lab", "Con"), 
                 votes1 = c(188, 200),
                 party2 = c("LD", "Lab"),
                 votes2 = c(140, 164),
                 party3 = c("Con", "LD"),
                 votes3 = c(23, 99))
setDT(df)# converting to data.table
```

Next I convert the df from wide to long form `x` so we can sum 'votes' according to 'district' and 'party'

```
x <- melt(df,id.vars = "district",  # Melting data to long
     measure.vars = patterns("^party", "^votes"),
     value.name = c("party", "votes"))
```

Which returns

```
#Displaying x
x
   district variable party votes
1:        A        1   Lab   188
2:        B        1   Con   200
3:        A        2    LD   140
4:        B        2   Lab   164
5:        A        3   Con    23
6:        B        3    LD    99
```

Now, I compute `y` - the sum according to district and party, and filter only the required "LD" party.

```
y <- x[party=="LD", .(SumV=sum(votes)), .(district, party)]
```

Finally, I append to df the column `SumV` from `y` to `df`. I am sorting `y` according to `district` to avoid having assigned the LD sums to different districts.

```
df[ , LD_votes:= y[order(district),SumV]]
df
   district party1 votes1 party2 votes2 party3 votes3 LD_votes
1:        A    Lab    188     LD    140    Con     23      140
2:        B    Con    200    Lab    164     LD     99       99
```

Similarly with Con and Lab parties

```
y <- x[party=="Lab", .(SumV=sum(votes)), .(district, party)]
df[ , Lab_votes:= y[order(district),SumV]]
y <- x[party=="Con", .(SumV=sum(votes)), .(district, party)]
df[ , Con_votes:= y[order(district),SumV]]
df
   district party1 votes1 party2 votes2 party3 votes3 LD_votes Lab_votes Con_votes
1:        A    Lab    188     LD    140    Con     23      140       188        23
2:        B    Con    200    Lab    164     LD     99       99       164       200
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate("LDVotes" = (ifelse(party1 == "LD", votes1, 0) + ifelse(party2 == "LD", votes2, 0) + ifelse(party3 == "LD", votes3, 0)),
         "LabVotes" = (ifelse(party1 == "Lab", votes1, 0) + ifelse(party2 == "Lab", votes2, 0) + ifelse(party3 == "Lab", votes3, 0)),
         "ConVotes" = (ifelse(party1 == "Con", votes1, 0) + ifelse(party2 == "Con", votes2, 0) + ifelse(party3 == "Con", votes3, 0)))
```

Comment: There are hundreds of party/vote column pairs. There needs to be a functional/vectorized solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse way which should work for many column pairs.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df %>%
  rowid_to_column(var = "orig_row") %>%
  gather(col, val, -c(orig_row, district)) %>%
  arrange(orig_row) %>%
  group_by(orig_row) %>%
  mutate(grp_num = (1 + row_number()) %/% 2,
         col = str_remove(col, "[0-9]")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(col, val) %>%
  mutate(votes = parse_number(votes))

df1 %>% count(party, district, wt = votes)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be able to be done better inline, but this works.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(district = c("A", "B"),
                 party1 = c("Lab", "Con"),
                 votes1 = c(188, 200),
                 party2 = c("LD", "Lab"),
                 votes2 = c(140, 164),
                 party3 = c("Con", "LD"),
                 votes3 = c(23, 99))

party <- df %>%
    select(district, starts_with("party")) %>%
    gather(key="col", value="party", starts_with("party"))
votes <- df %>%
    select(district, starts_with("votes")) %>%
    gather(key="col", value="votes", starts_with("votes"))
result <- party %>%
    select(-col) %>% 
    mutate(votes=votes$votes) %>% 
    group_by(party, district) %>% 
    summarise(total=sum(votes))

> result
  party district total
1 Con   A           23
2 Con   B          200
3 Lab   A          188
4 Lab   B          164
5 LD    A          140
6 LD    B           99
```